# How to set a JSP target to parent frame in Struts2?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, struts2

In my web application, there is one page(`.jsp`) which is divided into three frames. `AddCp.jsp` is in one frame of that JSP. Now on session timeout I want to show login page again. But the problem is this that the login page is coming in that frame only not on the whole window.

Below is the code snippet from `struts.xml`:

```
<action name="AddCP" class="com.appupdate.action.AppUpdateAction" method="addCP">
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/pages/AddCP.jsp</result>
        <result name="login" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">showLogin</param>
            <param name="namespace">/login</param>
            <param name="navigation">timeout</param>
            <param name="target">_parent</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

Could anyone please help? How can I change the target frame here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request should specify the target, response doesn't have any way to change it. You are getting that loaded in the frame from where request was initiated.

**[Edited]**

To confirm this, you can refer to this [JavaRanch thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/285087/JSP/java/redirect-target-parent).

---

**Solution:**

You can have a JavaScript statement in your `login.jsp`.

```
<script>
    if(parent.frames.length > 1)
        parent.location.href = '/showLogin';
</script>
```

Comment: Just a note: A server side view composition system such as Apache tiles should be a lot easier maintain than frames. It's worth looking into the struts2-tiles-plugin.

Comment: @Quaternion: Of course, I would also recommend tiles or sitemesh decorator.